# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_migrate'

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

I'm new to python+flask, and wanted to use flask to create a website.
The IDE is Visual studio 2017, and I could run the program successfully with flasky.py as startup file. But in CLI, I constantly got this error.

```
(sms) C:\Document\Workspace\smsserver\smsserver>flasky.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Document\Workspace\smsserver\smsserver\flasky.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_migrate import Migrate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_migrate'
```

The codes are:

```
import os
from os import environ
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from app import create_app, db
import app.models

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
....
```

Here are modules installed in the venv.

```
(sms) C:\Document\Workspace\smsserver\smsserver>pip freeze
alembic==1.0.7
...
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.3.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
....
SQLAlchemy==1.2.17
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.12.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
....
```

Is there anything I missed? Or any module confliction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CLI you need to run your script as follows:

```
python flasky.py
```

When you just run `flasky.py` Windows opens the script with the executable registered to handle the `.py.` extension on your system, which is your system-wide Python interpreter (i.e. not the interpreter associated with your virtual environment).

Comment: It works. Thank you! I misunderstood the virtual env and Python interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

Try reinstalling the Flask-Migrate. This worked for me

```
pip install Flask-Migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

Watch out when working out of a python virtual env:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

After activating the private/local python environment by:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Your PATH could be correctly updated but the shell hash **may still point to the OLD python / flask location!** (where the module is NOT installed)

Therefore to solve this you may just have to rehash at the shell by typing the following command:

```
hash -r
```

It solved this same problem for me.

Comment: Wow, it worked fine. Thanks a lot, it would have been hard to debug.

Comment: What I don't understand: `source .venv/bin/activate` usually works fine. Is this a bug in venv or in flask?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-flask-migrate -y
```

Answer (score 1):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 4, in 
from  flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
ImportError: cannot import name 'MigrateCommand' from 'flask_migrate'

use pip install flask-migrate==2.1.1 to solve

Answer (score 0):

1. `pip install Flask-Script==2.0.5`
2. `pip install Flask-Migrate==1.2.0`
3. create manage.py file in your root directory and add following code:

   ```
   from flask_script import Manager

   from <your app name> import app,db

   import os

   from config import Config

   from flask_migrate import Migrate,MigrateCommand

   from flask import Flask

   from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


   app.config.from_object(Config)

   migrate = Migrate(app, db)

   manager = Manager(app)

   manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

   if __name__ == '__main__':

       manager.run()
   ```
4. Apply following commands:

   ```
   python manage.py db init 
   python manage.py db migrate
   python manage.py db upgrade
   ```